# Datatable functionality in Meteor tabular package

Tags: jquery, meteor, datatables

*I've edited the code and explanation below, outlining the problem better following some further attempts at resolving*

I'm trying to add a row to a DataTable (created using aldeed:tabular in Meteor).  I am combining the [limited instructions on tabular](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular) with the [detailed instructions from DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html).

Using the code below:
- the table is rendering fine, so I know aldeed:tabular is working
- the jquery to hide the "test" button is working fine within the same template
- However, clicking the button to add a row returns nothing (debugger says Process finished with exit code 0)

lib/tables

```
TabularTables = {};

Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

TabularTables.Transactions = new Tabular.Table({
    name: "Transactions",
    collection: Transactions,
    columns: [
        {data: "company", title: "Target"},
        {data: "sector", title: "Acquirer"},
        {data: "company", title: "Enterprise Value"}
    ]
});
```

client/transactions.html

```
<template name="Transactions">
    <div>
        <div>
            <h3>Transactions</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="addRow">Add new row</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            {{> tabular table=TabularTables.Transactions class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"}}
        </div>
        <div>
            <p id="test">This is a jQuery test.</p>
            <button id="test-button">Click me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

client/transactions.js

```
Template.Transactions.rendered = function () {
    var t = $('TabularTables.Transactions').DataTable();
    $("#addRow").on( 'click' , function() {
        t.row.add( [
            "target",
            "acquirer",
            "1000"
        ] ).draw();
    });
    $("#test-button").click(function(){
        $("#test").hide();
    });
};
```

I posted this to the package's issues page, as well as to Meteor Forums, but I think my issue may be a more generic jquery issue so I thought this might be more appropriate.  Thank you.

Comment: I realized my issue was that my Tabular datatable was tied to a collection (the example on Datatables.net hardcodes the data in the table construction) that is not populated.  So there was nothing to add.  If I link to a populated collection, I at least see the data.  Then need to write arrays to choose what gets added and what does not